'Integrating' a matrix times a gradient
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $\nabla f = g$, where $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Further let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Does there always exist a function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla h = Ag$? If so, can it be recovered from $f$? Feel free to make any assumptions on $A$.

Something of interest may be the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

By Poincaré's lemma for star-shaped domains, we have that there exists an $F$ such that $\nabla h = Ag$ if and only if $A \nabla h$ is symmetric, where $\nabla g$ is the Jacobian of $g$ (assuming $F$ is $C^1$).
Hence it remains to check that $A \nabla g$ is symmetric -- we know that $\nabla g$ is symmetric, so it solely depends on the effect of multiplying by $A$ on the left. For example, if $A$ were symmetric and shared the same eigenvectors as $\nabla g$, that would be enough to conclude.

Let $f=x^2-y^2$.  And
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $A \nabla f = \langle -2y,2x \rangle$ which has a non-zero curl, which implies it is not a gradient function.
An even simpler example: $f(x,y) = xy$ and $A=diag(2,1)$.

Thanks! Do you know if there exists any conditions on $A$ such that it does hold, or they don't exist in general?

If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then I believe the result is true because $Ag$ is the gradient of $f$ with respect to the inner product induced by the spd matrix $A^{-1}$

@whpowell96 my second example is positive definite but does not yield a gradient function.  A non-isometric scaling can introduce curl when no curl was present.

Ah my mistake I misread that example. My intuition about the induced inner product missed that any induced curl is undone by the new inner product

@Tyler6 I don't think any such $A$ exists other than the trivial case where it is a scalar multiple of an identity matrix.

@Paul makes sense -- thanks very much!
